# Sealed get, abstract set in C# properties

Tags: c#, inheritance, properties

Does C# support this? What is the syntax for this?
I want the get of this property to be sealed (doesn't really matter), and the set of this to be abstract.
I've tried the following code (with incorrect syntax) to get the idea.

```
public sealed Texture target
{
    get { return texture; }
}
public abstract Texture target { set; }
```

and

```
public Texture target
{
    sealed get { return texture; }
    abstract set;
}
```

Comment: Which problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: I've answered the question as per the title (sealed get, abstract set) rather than the body (sealed set, abstract get). If you feel like making the question consistent with itself, I'll update my answer if needs be.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't *know* of syntax to do that, but you can easily implement a workaround which will only be ugly from the derived class's point of view:

```
public abstract class Base
{
    private string name;
    public string Name
    {
        get { return name; }
        set { SetName(value); }
    }

    protected abstract void SetName(string value);
}
```

On the other hand, it's not clear how `name` (or `texture` in your case) is ever going to be set, unless it's turned into a protected field (ick, IMO).

Could you give more information about what you're trying to achieve? There may be a better approach.

Comment: One option is to make the method `SetName(ref string field, string value)`, which I've seen and used in a similar way for implementing INotifyPropertyChanged and base-class validation cleanly.

Comment: Well if you don't know it, it probably doesn't exist! Texture is publicly set. Derived classes need to override the set to perform a type check and set it on the graphics card (which each texture type does differently).

Comment: @Hannesh: It sounds like the setter in the base class should still be setting the field then, but *also* calling a method to perform validation and the hardware-specific part.

Comment: Actually, that would certianly be the best thing to do. +1 for that

Answer (score 1):

It is not supported. What you could do is something like this:

```
public Texture target
{
    get { return texture; }
    set { SetTarget(value); }
}

protected abstract SetTarget(Texture target);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public abstract X GetXXX();

public sealed SetXXX(X x){...}
```